# When I try baking the left high poly object onto the right low poly one it ends up like this

Tags: shaders, normals, baking

When I try baking the left high poly object onto the right low poly one it ends up like this (The center is all black, you can still see the low poly edges even though I smoothed it out, and overall it looks horrible)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From the image, it looks like you baked your Normal Map to sRGB color space - make sure to use non-color space for your target "bake" image, and enable 32-bit float in the image options when you create it (if you haven't already) when baking Normal Maps. Also, is your low poly smooth shaded?

Comment: I forgot to enable 32-bit float, thank you